# Batch file that looks for a folder that contains 1 file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, directory

i have a lot of folders with a random number of files within. 
And the most of them just have 1 file inside it, these files needs to move to the parent folder. but i don't know how i should do it with a batch file.

I use Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*) DO (
 FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b/a-d "%%a\*.*" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') DO IF %%c==1 ECHO(MOVE "%%a\*.*" "%%a\..\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The `for /d /r` finds all of the subdirectory names starting at `sourcedir` and assigns thenm to `%%a` in turn.

Each directory is then examined for filenames only; the `2>nul` suppresses error messages for empty directories, and the output of the `dir` command is fed to `find` which counts (/c) the number of lines which **don't** match `""` (ie. counts the lines of directory = # files returned). This is applied to `%%c`

If `%%c` is 1, then move all (one) files from the directory to its parent.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Comment: Nicely done.  I provided my own PowerShell approach to the problem, which I believe leads to clearer and easier to understand code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution don't use any external .exe command, so it should run faster. Also, it is clear enough to be understood with no problems, I think...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /D %%d in (*) do (
   set "firstFile="
   set "moreThanOneFile="
   for %%f in ("%%d\*.*") do (
      if not defined firstFile (
         set "firstFile=%%f"
      ) else (
         set "moreThanOneFile=true"
      )
   )
   if not defined moreThanOneFile move "!firstFile!" "%%d"
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a number of folders that all may or may not contain files within them, and you want to move all files to some other directory?

PowerShell is the new and improved super charged version of using a batch file, and this is how you'll do it.

1. Run PowerShell
2. paste in the following

   dir -Recurse C:\FolderContainingManySubfolder | ? PSIsContainer | dir -Recurse | move-item -Destination T:\somePath -WhatIf

Replace C:\FolderContainingManySubfolder with the folder that has all of those other folders with one or two items each, and replace T:\somePath with the place you want the single files to go.

Run it, and you'll see a lot of 'What If' output, which shows you what would happen if you were to run the command.  If you're happy with what you see, then remove the -WhatIf parameter from the end.